# How can I remove the left padding of images in android studio?

Tags: android, xml

The padding in the left the image below don't look good. I want to remove that. How can I remove that?

[image: images]

Comment: In your parent layout remove `android:padding_left` and `android:padding_right`

Answer (score 1):

Please mention measurement also means "dp" or you can remove these two property from layout..

android:padding_left="0dp"

android:padding_right="0dp"

Answer (score 0):

try put `android:padding_left="0"` and `android:margin_left="0"`